# Program crush on [order setPrice:price] break point at @synthesize name

Tags: ios, objective-c

please help me to solve a simple problem.
I am a beginner in objective-c, and I am just switched to objective-c from java. I know java fair well, but not quite super deep into it.

I am building a iphone app. My app is quite simple.
The purpose of my iphone app is to take order with my iphone app in a restaurant.

**Progress of My App:**
My app only has couple viewPanels and buttons now :)
[Here](http://speedy.sh/Sd3vj/v1.zip) is my app sourcecode, firstview [screenshot](http://s14.postimage.org/kzhwfl4v5/B070_D9_B2_1_EBC_4_BB4_8004_8_D582_A235661.jpg) & secondview [screenshot](http://s7.postimage.org/adsnrnorf/7_CFDA2_E7_1137_4_C87_ADBE_6_EA578694239.jpg)

**Problem:**
When i click on the Coffee button, my textField wont show up the coffee name &  coffee price, which suppose to show up " coffee   1" .
and xcode will take me to the debugger from the iphone similator.(i think its crush at a line so the dubugger took me to the IBaction method and break at the line @synthesize name; It compiles with no error. please help trouble shoot why xcode take me to debugger when i press the coffee button.

[SCREEN SHOWS UP RIGHT AFTER PRESS THE COFFEE BUTTON](http://s7.postimage.org/9kicnwvff/C995356_B_66_BB_4_F9_A_8_DEF_26_CB5_A985_CF8.jpg)

here is the action code of the coffee button

```
- (IBAction)Coffee:(id)sender {
    int price = 1;
    NSString *name = @"coffee";

    Storage *order = [[Storage alloc] init];
    [order setName:name];               // i assume the program crush at here when it look into setName method.
    [order setPrice:price];
    [orders addOrders:order];

    // Sanity check:     // the program not even hit this line yet before crush;
    NSLog(@"There are now %d orders in the array.", [orders.getOrders count]);

    for (Storage *obj in orders.getOrders){
        [check setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj description]]];  // check is the TextField instant varible. and the description method is from storage.m to print out the name and price.
    }
}
```

The codes below are my storage classes that store all items that my customer orders.
it is a 2 dimensional array, and My **Storages** class is a wrapper class of **Storage** class.
the array format looks like this:

arrayindex1-> name, price

arrayindex2-> name, price

arrayindex3-> name, price

arrayindex4-> name, price

Storage.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Storage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger price;

@end
```

Storage.m

```
#import "Storage.h"

@implementation Storage

@synthesize name;         // program crush and goes to here.
@synthesize price;

- (NSString *)description {
    // example: "coffee 1"
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", self.name, self.price];
}

@end
```

Storages.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Storage.h"
@interface Storages : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray *orders;

-(void) addOrders:(Storage *)anOrder;
-(NSMutableArray *) getOrders;

@end
```

Storages.m

```
#import "Storages.h"

@implementation Storages
@synthesize orders;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        orders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) addOrders:(Storage *)anOrder{
    [orders addObject: anOrder];
}
-(NSMutableArray *) getOrders{
    return orders;
}
@end
```

Comment: it is the method in storage.m

Comment: can you please update storage.m with that method. I think error is in that method.

Comment: Why are you using *price instead of price?

Comment: @user2021373 `@property (nonatomic)NSInteger *price;`

Comment: Why did you use reference for setPrice?

Comment: if i dun use setPrice, how do i input the price into my storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

1) Don't use a pointer for the price property.  Generally, unless you're doing something unusual, your properties that are objects will be pointers and your properties that are primitives (NSInteger, BOOL, float, etc) will not be pointers.

2) You will want to make sure that the orders `NSMutableArray` is initialized with the `Storages` object, otherwise orders will remain nil and whenever you try to add objects to it, nothing will happen.  To initialize the `NSMutableArray`, do this in your `init` method as shown below.  You can also check that the object is actually getting into a valid mutable array this by putting a simple NSLog statement in the `for (Storage *obj in orders.getOrders) { ... }` loop and making sure you get at least one iteration through the loop.  If orders.getOrders is nil, the work block of the for loop will never get run.

3) It sounds like you need to override (and may have already overridden) the `-[NSObject description]`method for your Storage object.  My guess is you have a mismatch in this method with the `-[NSString stringWithFormat:...]` format string. For example, you might be using %d or %@ in the format string for the `NSInteger *`.  Something like that could definitely cause a crash (which is what I think you mean by "Xcode taking you to the debugger").  For NSIntegers you need to use %d or %i. And as myself and others have mentioned, you want `NSInteger` here and not `NSInteger *` and you should change your property declaration.

4) Based on what you have here, I don't think you need the `order` property in the `Storages` class at all.

5) Make sure you haven't overlooked the possibility of forgetting to hook up the IBOutlet in Interface Builder to the `check` textField.  A good test for this, besides just confirming it's connected in Interface Builder, would be a reality check test like `[check setText:@"This is a test."];`

6) Keep in mind that once this works, your for loop is going to execute very quickly, and you'll immediately see only the description for the last object in the orders array.  But that doesn't seem to be what your question is about.

I'd suggest you make the following changes:

Storage.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Storage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger price;

@end
```

Storage.m

```
#import "Storage.h"

@implementation Storage

@synthesize name;
@synthesize price;

- (NSString *)description {
    // example: "coffee 1"
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d", self.name, self.price];
}

@end
```

Your IBAction method

```
- (IBAction)Coffee:(id)sender {
    int price = 1;
    NSString *name = @"coffee";

    Storage *order = [[Storage alloc] init];
    [order setName:name];
    [order setPrice:price];
    [orders addOrders:order];

    // Sanity check:
    NSLog(@"There are now %d orders in the array.", [orders.getOrders count]);

    for (Storage *obj in orders.getOrders){
        [check setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj description]]];  // check is the TextField instant varible. and the description method is from storage.m to print out the name and price.
    }
}
```

Storages.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Storage.h"
@interface Storages : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong, readwrite) NSMutableArray *orders;

-(void) addOrders:(Storage *)anOrder;
-(NSMutableArray *) getOrders;

@end
```

Storages.m

```
#import "Storages.h"

@implementation Storages
@synthesize orders;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        orders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) addOrders:(Storage *)anOrder{
    [orders addObject: anOrder];
}
-(NSMutableArray *) getOrders{
    return orders;
}
@end
```

Comment: wow, thx for helping me to edit my crappy codes. After i changed all the codes u pointed out. the program still crush at [order setName:name]  at the IBAction method.

Comment: the program is not even hitting the log method u wrote for me. my console doesnot print out anything before crush.

Comment: Hey! Based on your last screenshot, "SCREEN SHOWS UP RIGHT AFTER PRESS THE COFFEE BUTTON", the app isn't crashing, it's just hitting user breakpoints that you've placed on the two `@synthesize` lines. Remove those two breakpoints (the blue things) by either grabbing them with the mouse and dragging them into the code area, or right-clicking each one and choosing "Delete Breakpoint" in the pull-down menu.  Once you remove those two breakpoints, your code should execute properly, and will work if you've made all of the changes above.

Comment: I took the Xcode project you posted and made the required changes, you can [see the code here](https://github.com/larrylegend/V1) and [download here](https://github.com/larrylegend/V1/archive/master.zip). It works. I won't leave this github repo up forever but at least for a couple of days so you can get a chance to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

What does description do in the following? (I cannot see any description object in Storage class):

```
[check setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[obj description]]];
```

I think if you want to print the name the do like:

```
[check setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",obj.name, obj.price]];
```

Comment: i need to print out both the name and price. in my description method i have already overrided it with my own method.

Comment: it still doesnot work, still take me back to the dubugger. i dun think its that line's problem.

Comment: At which line it redirects you to debugger? Also, did you initialise orders array?

Comment: it takes me to @synthesize name;   in storage.h

Comment: i did initialized orders array.  do u want me to upload my entire project?

Answer (score 0):

You have taken `NSInteger` pointer in `Storages` class which is not correct. `NSInteger` is basic data type and not a pointer. Remove that pointer and use `NSInteger` variable.
I hope this would resolve your problem.

You could use below code:

```
@interface Storage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic, assign)NSInteger price;
```

Comment: it doesnot work. = =   takes me back to the @synthesize name; in storage.h again

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes:
1- You declared price as an NSInteger and passed it as a reference. The correct is to pass it as an integer as it is and deal with it as an integer through the whole application.
2- You didn't initialize orders array in Storages class so it will be always nil and will not hold any added object.

***You code may looks like:***

In the button's IBAction pass the price directly

```
[order setPrice:price];
```

In the Storage class

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@        %d", name, price];
}
```

Add the following to the Storages class

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        orders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , i already updated the codes, but my program still crush before it hits the orders.  The break point at [order setPrice:price];

Comment: I downloaded the application you posted and it runs normally.